# Loading Breeze via AMD

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, breeze, amd

I try to use Breeze together with: TypeScript, AMD modules, requirejs, knockout.

Looking at the Breeze code, I can see that it requires knockout via the name "ko". However, there are other components which require knockout via the name "knockout".

So, if I create a configuration for requirejs with the path "knockout", the loader will complain that "ko" has not been loaded yet. If I manually change the Breeze code, replacing "ko" with "knockout" anything works fine.

What can be done, so changing the Breeze code is not necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [map config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) to remap any request that breeze makes for 'ko' to 'knockout'. Something like this:

```
require.config({
    //
    // your other config (e.g. paths)
    //

    // remap requests for 'ko'
    map: {
        'breeze': {
            'ko': 'knockout'
        }
    }
});
```

Or if you want to map those requests for 'ko' from **all** modules, you can use * wildcard:

```
map: {
    '*': {
        'ko': 'knockout'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The map config was a good hint. I had to modify the code just a little bit: using "breeze" as the ID did not work, but "*" did.

Comment: @mgs thanks, added that to the answer to make it easier for others who may see it.